# typescript extending from generic parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a class where I can extends from a generic parameter.
This seems not to be possible. What I tried is this:

```
abstract class VayuModule<P extends VayuModuleProps, S extends 

VayuModuleState> extends React.Component<P, S> {
    ...
}

class Button extends VayuModule<any, any> {
  ...
}

class Test<T extends VayuModule<any,any>> {
}

class EditorModule<T extends VayuModule<any,any>> extends Test<T> {

}

class ButtonEditor extends EditorModule<Button> {

}
```

Error results in "Cannot find name 'T'.ts(2304)".

Comment: Syntactically I think you mean class Test<T> implements T but it would not be possible to implement an unknown type.  You would probably want to create the class through a factory function so that you can assert the return type.  You would take an object of type T and use it to dynamically set properties on the class.  You would then need to assert that your class instance is in fact of type T as well as class<T>.  Can you explain further what you are trying to do?

Comment: Is T another class?  You might be thinking about something like mixins where you extend a class which is a variable: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html

Comment: It depends strongly on what kind of "extending"  you plan to do.  [This](https://tsplay.dev/w26Pbw) may or may not meet your needs, or you might need mixins as mentioned above.

Comment: sorry my coding was a bit unclear, hope it gets clearer soon, i updated it above, basically i have a class Button which extends from VayuModule. There should be class called ButtonEditor which extends from andother class called EditorModule. This class EditorModule should then extend again back from Button defined as the generic Parameter